# Stripe Reporting API - trying to use the Stripe CLI to retrieve reporting data

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe payments for an upcoming integration and I have setup the Stripe CLI so I can communicate to my test setup using my terminal and this all works fine.

I am trying to run some reporting to retrieve some payout reconciliation data

```
stripe reporting report_types retrieve payout_reconciliation.itemized.5
```

This returns the following response

```
{
  "id": "payout_reconciliation.itemized.5",
  "object": "reporting.report_type",
  "data_available_end": 1705276800,
  "data_available_start": 1702944000,
  "default_columns": [
    "automatic_payout_id",
    "automatic_payout_effective_at",
    "balance_transaction_id",
    "created",
    "available_on",
    "currency",
    "gross",
    "fee",
    "net",
    "reporting_category",
    "description"
  ],
  "livemode": false,
  "name": "Itemized payout reconciliation",
  "updated": 1705302416,
  "version": 5
}
```

So I know my CLI is setup but I want to use the parameters to filter by start and end date - by doing the following

```
stripe reporting report_types retrieve payout_reconciliation.itemized.5 --interval_start=1702944000 --interval_end=1705276800
```

I am using the stripe reporting docs here - https://stripe.com/docs/reports/report-types/payout-reconciliation
[image]

When I run the following command with the start and end dates I get an error?

```
$ stripe reporting report_types retrieve payout_reconciliation.itemized.5 --interval_start=1702944000 --interval_end=1705276800
unknown flag: --interval_start
```

I am confused as the parameters appear to be correct according to the API documentation - what an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the Report Run API works is you first 'create a report run' specifying the parameters of the run, and then later when the run is complete, you get a webhook and can then access the results.

You don't retrieve data for a given interval by simply passing parameters to a GET (`retrieve`) call as in the examples you shared; instead you create (a POST request, `create`) a Report Run for the given interval you're interested in and then get the report async.

Furthermore, the values are passed to `parameters`, not at the top level:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/reporting/report_run/create#create_reporting_report_run-parameters-interval_end

So putting all that together:

```
stripe reporting report_runs create --report-type="payout_reconciliation.itemized.5" --data parameters[interval_start]=1702944000 --data parameters[interval_end]=1705276800
```

(as also seen in the example at https://stripe.com/docs/api/reporting/report_run/create?lang=cli#create_reporting_report_run-parameters-interval_end)

That creates the ReportingRun object, and when the requested data is available and the report is done, you can retrieve the results; see https://stripe.com/docs/reports/api#report-runs

Comment: cheers i'll give that a go! You know your stuff on stripe thanks will accept your answer once i've got it all working @Karllekko